# Specify a specific year to be updated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm dealing with an old database that contains records of 365 days of the past 3 years. I'm trying to get the 2016 records 'for example' and change the year to 2020 and then add my new record to the table so it would contain now records of 4 years.
this is what I did so far :

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR , 2020- year(Date),Date) as Date_Modified,Date from Date
```

I want to make `where` condition to specify the year is 2016 so it would update the records with the year 2016. how to do that ?? I tried `where year()=2016` it was an error.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: No one is a mind reader. Nor can they see your screen when you execute your code. Post the complete and exact error message - ALL of it include number, severity, etc.

Comment: there is no error message the select statement works fine. I'm asking how to write the where condition to specify the year. this is how the date inserted `Feb  1 2016 12:00AM` . I was trying to write the where condition as `where year=2016` but it's incorrect

Comment: What is the data type of your date column?

Comment: @forpas nvarchar

Comment: Why do you store dates as nvarchar? You have such a simple situation here,to update a date and you must convert to date, add 4 years and convert back to nvarchar. What will you do when you must sort the table by date? Change your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more way to do it:

```
Insert into testT
select DATEADD(YEAR , 2020- year(Date_c),Date_c)
from testT
where year(Date_c) = '2016'
```

This insert statement will take data that have date in year 2016 and insert them as year 2020.

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52f0d2a21d21688b8080ab34be5a17e0)
In this DEMO the example table is named `testT` and your date column `Date_c`. YOu can also see a elect statement that will return only the rows that have date in year 2016.

Comment: Careful with `where year(Date_c) = '2016'`; the clause won't be SARGable, so won't be able to make use of any indexes.

Comment: Adding that `year(Date_c) = '2016'` is not sargable so a full table scan will be required even if the column is indexed. With a full year, a scan will probably be done anyway unless date is the clustered index.

Comment: It is only a insert for 1000 rows. I think it is ok.

Comment: It's not a problem of the `INSERT`, @VBoka , it's the finding the rows in the source table.

Comment: I know it is a select in this insert statement you are referring to. I believe that is clear and that is why I wrote "insert for 1000 rows". Again, as I wrote, only for 3 years and in every year 365 rows = around 1000 rows. I do not see a problem.

Comment: `create table test (Date_c date)`. the date column I have types nvarchar not date . That's why I tried your condition and it didn't give me any results. any suggestions on how to specify the year?

Comment: Then you ***need*** to fix your design, @2766 .

Comment: @2766 it does give results(check the demo, it does the insert): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62167193bf73e7234899375c80cb9046

Comment: @Larnu Unfortunately that is not my design nor am I allowed to edit in it.

Comment: Then you have some major data design problems, @2766 . For example, I can assure you that `2019-04-31` is not **before** `2016-12-01`, however, according to your data it is

Comment: @VBoka the select statement worked. thank you. But the insert gives me this error  _Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition._  and my code is `Insert into Date
select DATEADD(YEAR , 2020- year(Date),Date)
from Date
where year(Date) = '2016'` what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: @VBoka do I need to change the column to `Date_modified` to take its values and insert it in the original table ??? or what

Comment: @2766 no no, only the 'INSERT' statement will be ok. The statement that I wrote here. Here is the demo again on this link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=660a8e5b4af2eaba6b90f72fda830983 There you can see I have entered 3 rows of data. First row has a date that is representing year 2016th, second row 2017th and third row 2018th. My insert statement takes the row that is representing year 2016th, ads to that data 4 years and inserts that new row in the existing table so now you have 4 rows of data...

Comment: Also, @2766 please without writing of three questions marks, one is just enough... and sometimes it is nice to write "please can you explain"... or something similar to that and not the way you are writing. You need help from people and you want it for free here so try to be nice to people.

Comment: About the error you are receiving,your table "Date", how many columns does it have ? If there are two columns like for example "Name" and "Date" then you can not insert it like this. You will have tro try something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3c4ca0477b2b2c8fb9eb3e84a1cd643

Comment: @VBoka I'm so sorry. I didn't mean to be rude . of course, I really do appreciate your help. I'm just going crazy from the error . My code is the same as the one you showed me in the Demo and i can't figure out why I get the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205831/discussion-between-vboka-and-2766).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want logic like this:

```
select dateadd(year, 4, date) as new_date
from t
where date >= '2016-01-01' and date < '2017-01-01';
```

This works for 2016 and 2020 because both are leap years.

Comment: may I ask, what 4 refers to?

Comment: the date inserted like this ```Feb  2 2016 12:00AM```

Comment: Dates don't have a format, @2766 . The format `yyyy-MM-dd` is unanbiguous in SQL Server for the *newer* data types (it is not for `datetime`). As for the `4`, it's an integer; it refers to nothing, it is a number.

Comment: @2766 4 is adding 4 years to the actual date. If you add 3 it will add 3 years.